# Store select query's output in one array in postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

My code is:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information.SCHEMA.columns
WHERE table_name = 'aean'
```

It returns column names of table `aean`.
Now I have declared an array:

```
DECLARE colnames text[]
```

How can I store select's output in colnames array.
Is there any need to initialize colnames?

Comment: +1, I reached here with exact same error message- ERROR:  could not find array type for data type information_schema.sql_identifier. Was trying with `array_agg(column_name, ',')`

Comment: [This one gives me an answer. Questions are similar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541292/postgresql-column-names-into-array-pl-pgsql)

Answer (score 231):

There are two ways. One is to aggregate:

```
SELECT array_agg(column_name::TEXT)
FROM information.schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'aean'
```

The other is to use an array constructor:

```
SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT column_name 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = 'aean'
)
```

I'm presuming this is for plpgsql. In that case you can assign it like this:

```
colnames := ARRAY(
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name='aean'
);
```

Comment: can you give me the code that works on postgres because this is not working on postgres         ERROR:  could not find array type for data type information_schema.sql_identifier

Comment: Sorry 'bout that. Mindless copying and pasting got array_agg() included in all three calls. I've also type-casted the initial one to make your PG version happy.

Comment: For anyone looking further on the plpgsql part you can `DECLARE` an array as `my_array INTEGER[];` (or whatever the relevant type is). You can also use the array in a query's `WHERE` clause like `WHERE values = ANY(my_array)`. The `ANY` takes an array or a set and will check for presence in that array/set, so it functions equivalently to `IN ()` in a sense

Comment: The examples above should be `information_schema`, not `information.schema`.

Answer (score 17):

I had exactly the same problem. Just one more working modification of the solution given by Denis (the type must be specified):

```
SELECT ARRAY(
SELECT column_name::text
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name='aean'
)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the case anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Regular:

```
SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE(poster_name='John');

output: [
  {'post_id': 1},
  {'post_id': 2},
  {'post_id': 3},
]
```

Using `ARRAY_AGG`:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(post_id) FROM posts WHERE(poster_name='John');

output: [
 {[1, 2, 3]}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Casting to the datatype "TEXT" will ensure that your queries will run without any problem.
In plpgsql when we assign to a array variable, we need not use the type casting. My requirement was to get a CSV of all the column names of a particular table. I'd used the following code in plpgsql.

```
Declare col_list varchar[]:=NULL;
cols varchar:=NULL;
Begin
    col_list := ARRAY(select t.name from frm_columns t where t.tname='emp_mstr');
    cols := array_to_string(col_list,',');
    return cols;
End;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test_array(in _colname text)
returns text as $body$
DECLARE colnames text[];
begin
colnames := ARRAY(
    SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='customer'
);
    if exists(select _colname = any(colnames))
    then return format('%s it exits.', _colname);
    else return format('%s not exits.', _colname);
end if;
end
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

check if the column exists or not.
Key point:  `if exists(select _colname = any(colnames))`
We can also using `string_agg`
**String_agg** usage:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test_array1(in _colname text)
returns text as $body$
DECLARE colnames text;
begin
colnames := (SELECT string_agg(column_name,',') FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='customer')::text;
if exists(select colnames ilike '%' || quote_literal(_colname) ||'%')
    then return format('column %s  exits.', _colname);
    else return format('column %s does not exits.', _colname);
end if;
end
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

declare colnames text[] array in function and then write following query in begin:

SELECT column_name into colnames
FROM information.SCHEMA.columns
WHERE table_name = 'aean'