# Apply division to each element in column of type array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column box_coordinates of type integer[4] and I want to divide each element of the array by 640 and insert it into a new column of type float[4]. I first try to divide each element of the array before aggregating

```
SELECT n/640::float
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(box_coordinates) 
    FROM images 
) AS n;
```

but it fails with error

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: record / integer
HINT:   No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
        You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How do I apply the array element division and then insert the result into a new column of type float[4], while keeping the order of the elements in the new array unchanged?

Answer (score 2):

you are using `n` instead `unnest` result

```
SELECT n.coord/640::float
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(box_coordinates) as coord
    FROM images 
    LIMIT 4
) AS n;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Could you please edit your post to answer how you would insert it to a new column of type float[4]?

Comment: You need `array_agg()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402043/store-select-querys-output-in-one-array-in-postgres