# TWO RESULTS in SAME ROW in POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select * from Table1
where Condition 1
union 
select select * from Table1
where Condition 2
```

---

RESULTS:

```
NAME    AMOUNT    TYPE   
ABC      --       Account
ABC      200        --
```

---

but i need the results in one row  like

```
NAME     AMOUNT     TYPE
ABC       200       ACCOUNT
```

---

How to do in PG?

Comment: What you want is a `JOIN` not a `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

Base on your sample data, this may work

```
SELECT name,
       MAX(amount) amount,
       MAX(type) type
  FROM table1
 WHERE condition 1
    OR condition 2
 GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved something like that with the following:

```
select TABLE_1.DESCRIPTION_COLUMN,

(array(select TABLE_2.INFO_COLUMN from TABLE_2 where TABLE_1.ID = TABLE_2.ID_TABLE_1))[1],
(array(select TABLE_2.INFO_COLUMN from TABLE_2 where TABLE_1.ID = TABLE_2.ID_TABLE_1))[2]

from TABLE_1


WHERE TABLE_1 = 1
```

Source/Help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6402163/1856745